# Why am I getting this error when using Next.js middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, middleware, next-auth

### The Problem

I'm using Next.js, Prisma, and NextAuth's Email Provider strategy to setup an authentication system. I want to use Next.js middleware to redirect a request if it doesn't contain a valid session. But any use of the middleware, like literally just having a function declared in the middleware.js file, throws this error:

```
error - (middleware)/node_modules/oidc-token-hash/lib/shake256.js (3:0) @ <unknown>
error - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substr')
null
```

It logs this error about 5 times. This is the `middleware.js` file at `{root}/middleware.js`

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export default function middleware(request) {
  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

And here is this the `node_modules/oidc-token-hash/lib/shake256.js` file specified in the error:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const [major, minor] = process.version.substr(1).split('.').map((x) => parseInt(x, 10));
const xofOutputLength = major > 12 || (major === 12 && minor >= 8);
const shake256 = xofOutputLength && crypto.getHashes().includes('shake256');

module.exports = shake256;
```

Prior to creating this file, the app worked perfectly. I could authentiate via an email link, make simple GET requests to API routes, and do any other functionality. I've never seen this error before. The closest I can guess is that I have some sort of dependency/versioning issue, but I'm using damn near latest versions of Next, React, Prisma, NextAuth, Node, etc.

Perhaps it's worth noting that I'm using React Query? Other than that I have no idea what might be causing this.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nextjs-starter-auth-sql",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.4",
    "@prisma/client": "^4.3.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "next": "12.2.5",
    "next-auth": "^4.10.3",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.8",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "eslint": "^8.23.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.5",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "prisma": "^4.3.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
  }
}
```

Happy to answer any questions you may have. Your help is truly appreciated.

Comment: in which folder did you set up your middleware?

Comment: Are you sure this is the whole content of `middleware.js`? I got similar error when indirectly importing `next-auth` in `middleware.js`. Next.js creates a sandbox for the middleware by removing properties of `process`, while some libraries require it.

Answer (score 14):

I was running into this issue because I was importing the config from `[...nextauth].ts` into my `middleware.ts` module. It seems that the middleware cannot use exports from other modules that also use `next-auth`.

I was able to solve it by moving the part of the config I needed to its own dedicated module and then importing from that module in `[...nextauth].ts` and `middleware.ts` respectively.

### Before, *not* working

```
// src/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts
import type { AuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import Auth0Provider from 'next-auth/providers/auth0';

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/signin',
  },
  providers: [/* your providers */],
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

```
// src/middleware.ts
import { withAuth } from 'next-auth/middleware';

//  Cannot import from other modules that depend on `next-auth`.
import { authOptions } from '@/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]';

export default withAuth({
  pages: authOptions.pages,
});
```

### After, working

```
// src/config/pages.ts
export const pages = {
  signIn: '/auth/signin',
};
```

```
// src/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts
import type { AuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import Auth0Provider from 'next-auth/providers/auth0';

import { pages } from '@/config/pages';

export default NextAuth({
  pages,
  providers: [/* your providers */],
});
```

```
// src/middleware.ts
import { withAuth } from 'next-auth/middleware';

// ✅ Import the static config - does not use `next-auth`.
import { pages } from './config/pages';

export default withAuth({
  pages,
});
```

Comment: This is correct. I'm using the app router with middleware and in my case, I was simply importing a constant that was in a file that used next-auth. I moved the utilities that use next-auth to another page and then the importing worked.

Comment: Thanks man you saved my day, I was looking for an answer since past 2 days.

Answer (score 2):

For people using Auth0, this issue arises if not using the /edge package.

For eg,

`Replace this import { getSession } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';`

with this

`Replace this import { getSession } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0/edge';`

Answer (score 0):

This error ended up being a red herring for me, a bug further up the chain in my authentication middleware ended up triggering it.

If the accepted answer doesn't work for you unfortunately you may need to debug your next auth middleware line by line - this error message can superseded a more relevant error message for the actual bug causing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got into the exact same issue and solved it by upgrading the version of `next-auth` to `next-auth@beta`

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, I tried several ways including this one in the documentation

- https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/edge-middleware#creating-edge-middleware
- https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware

Although, the only way I got to solve it was to make downgrade of Nextjs version to "12.1.0".

Remove node_modules folder and package-lock.json, after that reinstall dependencies using command "npm install" with version "next": "12.1.0" in package.json and try again.

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).